# Create a Python List based upon the start of a string

Tags: python, list, filter

I'm currently attempting to create a program that sorts logs based on time stamp. The logs are in the following format:

> @ 2014 00:05:34 Jason "login" 0.01
>
> @ 2014 00:10:34 Jason "firefox" 0.01
>
> #server crashed
>
> @ 2014 00:11:54 Jason "logoff" 0.01

I'm reading these logs from files on the computer named log.1 and log.2.

My plan is to first remove all lines start with "#" as the commented lines are not going to be needed to be sorted... unless there is a better way to be doing this.

In order to remove all lines that start with "#", my plan was to use list comprehension. Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    Logs = []
    getLogs(Logs)
    sortLogs(Logs)

def getLogs(L):
    Log1 = sys.argv[1]
    Log2 = sys.argv[2]
    L1 = read(Log1)
    L2 = read(Log2)
    L.append(L1)
    L.append(L2)

def sortLogs(L):
    sLog = [i for i in L if i.startswith('@')]
    print(sLog)

def read(fName):
    return open(fName, "r").readlines()

main()
```

Unfortunately, I get the error of "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'". Can anyone provide some insight as to why I'm getting this error or my technique isn't working?

I've also done the following in Python IDE and it has worked:

```
>>> newlist = ['@test','new','#no','pleasework']
>>> finallist = [x for x in newlist if x.startswith('@')]
>>> finallist
['@test']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following small piece of code:

First I have two lists

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4]
lst2 = [2,3,4,5]
```

Then I am creating a new list and appending the above twos like you did in your code:

```
l = list()
l.append(lst1)
l.append(lst2)
```

Now, I am printing the type of the first element from the new list.

```
print type(l[0])
```

It says `<type 'list'>` and this is what your problem. You are having two lists in your new list, and that's why the `startswith()` didn't work for you.

So, whats the solution? replace `append()` with `extend()` and it will do.